# Automatic Post Questions to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, robots

is it legal to make a tool to get question from other forums and to post questions to StackOverflow ? Comunity from here is bigger than comunity from other places.

Comment: Can't speak for legal, but it certainly wouldn't be well recieved. How would the tool answer requests for clarification?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a smart plan. You also would miss the SO formatting and such, and you still have to look through the answers and comments etc, so why not just take te time to make a good and clear question yourself?

Comment: Ok, thanks :) . I just asked .

Comment: p.s. I feel upvotes are in order for asking  first rather than just letting this thing loose on stack overflow

Comment: @Richard very true, I initially downvoted (instinct! ;)) then on second thought changed my mind as the user only ask and didn't yet do that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's fine when exist communication,I just aks :). Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for asking before doing so. The thing is, we're rather particular about our questions. We have an idea about what constitutes a good question that might not necessarily match the standards of other sites. And we're rather fond of the idea that we're not a forum, but a Q&A.

With that in mind, it's highly likely that the questions on other sites are not a good fit for any of the sites in our network. And this doesn't even take into account potential issues with content copying and licences and such.

So while you might technically be able to do this, I wouldn't recommend it. If you have a good question for any of our sites, just ask it, and make sure that it matches our specific guidelines and fits within our boundaries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wanted to add question and comments in two ways,but now I tottaly agree with you.